# Dynamic information in my include file

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using `@include('folder.mypage')` as usual however my include page contains dynamic information. Unfortunately the dynamic information is not being included. How do I get round this?

Comment: You can bind data to view using ViewComposers.

Comment: Sorry I made the schoolboy error of not having blade as an extension for my include files.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass dynamic information from your view to the include by including an array of data.

```
@include('view.name', ['some' => 'data'])
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures

Comment: I need to ask my question another way to get a more detailed answer.